# Setting a bounty for a question to get answer quicker

Tags: feature-request, bounties

Awarding a bounty can help to get more views to your question. However, if the question is very detailed and not answered (without bounty active yet), wouldn't it be nice if every up-vote to that question would receive +20 for a vote up? I'd really like to have a question answered on SO, but I do not want to lose my permissions due to it.

Are there any possibilities left to get more attention without activating a bounty?
- Please note I know a bounty is meant to get more attention.

Answer (score 10):

The ways to draw attention to a question are:

- offer a bounty (this is what they're designed for, with one exception<sup>1</sup>)
- publicize the question to people who might be able to answer, e.g. through social media (there are even badges for this)

The voting system is fundamental to Stack Exchange; making it context-dependent like you propose does not seem productive, and I don't see the merit of this specific suggestion.  What does voting rep for the asker of the question have to do with the current publicity level of the question?  The bounty is already drawing more eyeballs which should draw votes if the question is well-asked.

And yes, bounties cost rep and can be risky; I've had more than one expire without getting an answer.  Think of the bounty as buying *attention* (and potentially an answer), not buying *an answer*.

---

<sup>1</sup> There is a bounty reason for "this has an answer that merits an additional reward", but even with that one you can't award it right away.  The primary function of the bounty is to give extra attention to the question.

Comment: I'd really like to set up a bounty for a specific question which I didn't get enough attention from. However, I think the question in case has enough detail, I doubt I get enough upvotes to pay for bounty (e.g. +100). I'd rather give out a +500 bounty for the answer, if I knew for sure I'd get at least 450 back in reputation. But I might think of the system wrongly then.

Comment: "Think of the bounty as buying attention (and potentially an answer), not buying an answer." - made me think, thanks.